# Adding reference to c#

Tags: c#

In my application i want use CAVEditLib.dll reference.But i can't find the library in COM reference.I am getting error as "Error    1   The type or namespace name 'CAVEditLib' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

What may the problem?

Comment: Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting CAVEditLib.dll in a lib folder in the same folder as where your solution resides then instead of adding a COM refrence, use "Browse" and add the reference from the actual file.

Comment: Try @rodrigovedovoto's approach below.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to register your library? Go to the command prompt, cd to the folder where your  library is located and execute "regsvr32 /i CAVEditLib.dll". This should work

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your solution. I am getting message as "CAVEditLib.dll is loaded. But DllInstall entry point was not found. The file cannot be registered".

Comment: I've downloaded this library and it seems this is the right procedure. But it needs to be done in the folder where the library originally came from (the result of the solid-ffmpeg-wrapper.zip unzip)

Answer (score 1):

Put your `CAVEditLit.dll` in the `debug` folder of your project.

One more thing you can do is..
In Visual Studio Menu

---

`Project`

`Add Reference`

and then in the new dialog click on the Browse tab and select your dll.

This will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am having it in debug folder.

Answer (score 1):

To use an external library in your code you need to:

1. Add a reference to it.
2. Add a using in the code file where you are using the library.

   `using CAVEditLib`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In the using CAVEditLib statement only i am getting the error.

Comment: Try using an intermediate language inspector like ILSpy on your DLL and check if it has a namespace or type named CAVEditLib inside.

Comment: Yeah looks like you are trying to use a namespace that doesn't exist.